# Docker: unable to set image memory limit

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu, redis, sentry

I am running [Sentry](https://github.com/getsentry/self-hosted) on prem, using `Ubuntu` and `Docker`, the problem is:
`sentry` is using `redis`, but `redis` container is eating up all the server memory.

I tried to set it up from `redis` itself, but it didn't actually applied even though `redis-cli` returning the correct `maxmemory` value.

I am trying to set the limit to the image itself using:

```
docker run -it --memory="2g" sentry_redis
```

And getting the following error:

```
Unable to find image 'sentry_redis:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for sentry_redis, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

Noting that the image does actually exists:

```
root@sentry# docker-compose ps
                           Name                                          Command               State               Ports            
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                
sentry_redis                                      docker-entrypoint.sh redis ...   Up       6379/tcp
```

any help

Comment: @Philippe same thing.

Comment: Try `docker run -it --memory="2g" sentry`